# How to detect Bluetooth version on Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am currently developing BLE app and I would like to filter discovered devices and leave only BLE compatible ones in the list.

Using Broadcom API it was fairly easy to find out if the device is BLE.
 Unfortunately DROID RAZR doesn't provide broadcom library so I had to use Motorola BLE library... and with no surprises they don't have a method to check bluetooth version.

I read all the possible native Android Bluetooth classes and did not manage to find relevant information to me (I found categories - pc, smartphones etc, but no version.)

Does anyone know how to check scanned device Bluetooth version?

Comment: Have you tried importing the Broadcom API?

Comment: As I said. I cannot use Broadcom API on my phone. It works fine on emulator, but if I want it to be on the phone I need to use uses-library, which is not allowed to do (by android). So I had to use their native Motorola API

Answer (score 1):

When you discovered devices, if you can got the android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice for the Bluetooth devices ,maybe you can use the Android official Api BluetoothDevice.getType() for you to filter the classic or ble devices.

```
/**
 * Get the Bluetooth device type of the remote device.
 *
 * <p>Requires {@link android.Manifest.permission#BLUETOOTH}
 *
 * @return the device type {@link #DEVICE_TYPE_CLASSIC}, {@link #DEVICE_TYPE_LE}
 *                         {@link #DEVICE_TYPE_DUAL}.
 *         {@link #DEVICE_TYPE_UNKNOWN} if it's not available
 */
public int getType() {
    if (sService == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "BT not enabled. Cannot get Remote Device type");
        return DEVICE_TYPE_UNKNOWN;
    }
    try {
        return sService.getRemoteType(this);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {Log.e(TAG, "", e);}
    return DEVICE_TYPE_UNKNOWN;
}
```